# how many JVMs are running when Spark Local mode is used?

Tags: apache-spark

newbie here, but really enjoyed Spark so far.

I did the following (using a laptop, running Windows 7):

1. start the master by using command prompt window:

   `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`
2. start one worker by typing the following:

   `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://localhost:7077`
3. repeat step 2, in other words, start another worker by using the same above command.

Now, I have one master, two workers, **all** in the same physical machine. Based on what I have been reading, this should be considered as the "`local mode`"... not sure about this, hope someone can confirm?

Also, from what I have read, `local mode` should have master and workers in one **SINGLE** JVM. But by running a small utility code, I can see that master is in one JVM, and two workers each stays in one JVM, so there are three JVMs, and they are different JVMs.

Can someone tell me which part I did wrong, or, what is the problem with my understanding?

Also, for this `local model`, there is no cluster manager, right?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I have one master, two workers, all in the same physical machine. Based on what I have been reading, this should be considered as the "local mode"... not sure about this, hope someone can confirm?

It is not. It is a [standalone mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html), where you Spark's own cluster manager. Unlike `local` it is fully distributed. It will use:

- For cluster manager:

  - Single JVM for each cluster master (one in your case, more in HA  mode).
  - Single JVM for each started worker.
  - Optionally additional JVMs for services like history server, or shuffle service.
- For application:

  - Single JVM for the driver.
  - Single JVM for each executor.

In local mode there is only one JVM, as already [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363079/8371915) by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2969037/greg)

Answer (score 4):

Local mode is a single JVM.  Local mode is when you specify the master, via --master command line switch, as local[*].  This can be done via spark-submit or spark-shell.

[This](https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/apache-spark-internals/latest/spark-local/index.html) explains it pretty well.

Comment: yep. Thanks. I think what I did in the question (creating the master, the worker, etc..) was actually simulating a standalone mode by using one physical machine, it is not local mode. thanks.

Comment: You should probably accept this as well. It seems to answer your question.

Comment: Suggested edit for broken link as [resource has moved](https://medium.com/@jaceklaskowski/the-internals-of-apache-spark-has-moved-f40467945669)

Comment: Edited as requested.